# How to generate pattern matching using quasiqoutes for each type of sealed trait?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I've got the following macro and I'm trying to generate the following function

```
(event: Event, state: State) => State
```

My macro

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object GenericEventHandlerMacro {

  def generateGenericEventHandlerMacro[E, S](): (E, S) => S = macro generateGenericEventHandlerMacroImpl[E, S]

  def generateGenericEventHandlerMacroImpl[E: c.WeakTypeTag, S: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val subclasses: Set[c.universe.Symbol] = c.weakTypeOf[E].typeSymbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses

    val cases = subclasses.map {
      (subClass: c.universe.Symbol) =>
        val className = subClass.fullName.substring(subClass.fullName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, subClass.fullName.length)
        val simpleNameHandler = TermName(className + "EventHandler")
        val caseType = subClass.asType.name
        cq"""event: $caseType => $simpleNameHandler.processEvent(event, state)"""
    }

    val eventType: c.universe.Symbol = c.weakTypeOf[E].typeSymbol
    val stateType: c.universe.Symbol = c.weakTypeOf[S].typeSymbol

    val theCode =
      q"""(event: ${eventType.asType}, state: ${stateType.asType}) =>
        event match {
          case ..$cases
        }
      """
    println(showCode(theCode))
    theCode
  }
}
```

Code to run

```
sealed trait Event
case class Event1(id: String) extends Event
case class Event2() extends Event

trait State
case class State1(id: String) extends State

object Test extends App {
  val genericEventHandlerGenerator = GenericEventHandlerMacro.generateGenericEventHandlerMacro[Event, State]()

  genericEventHandlerGenerator(Event1("event"), State1("state"))
}
```

**Output**

`sbt compile` prints out the following which is incorrect.

```
((event: Event, state: State) => event match {
  case (event @ ((_): Event1)) => Event1EventHandler.processEvent(event, state)
  case (event @ ((_): Event2)) => Event2EventHandler.processEvent(event, state)
})
```

expected output

```
((event: Event, state: State) => event match {
  case (event: Event1) => Event1EventHandler.processEvent(event, state)
  case (event: Event2)) => Event2EventHandler.processEvent(event, state)
})
```

Comment: did you run the generated code? It looks correct.

Comment: Yes you are right. It works ... It's just Intellij didn't recognized that syntax. All fixed. I should delete this question

Comment: Macro compiler generates output that includes constructs like `case (e@_)` and `def <init> ...`, which are not valid in normal Scala code. So basically you cannot just copy and paste `show`/`showCode` results into a worksheet and make it compile without some modifications

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks for the info ... I will keep that in mind for future reference when working on macros.